# RegistrationType.Transient for only some viewmodels

Tags: catel

I was wondering if it's possible in Catel to specify that some viewmodels are by default with RegistrationType.Transient. I mean if a user opens 2 times the sameviewmodel (for example to work on different orders) I want to have the viewmodel to be a new one. Is this possible using an interceptor? If needed I can decorate the viewmodels with a custom attribute

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModels are always transient. This means that a new view model will be created for you when you need one.

This is all done by the `IViewModelFactory`. Since everything in Catel can be customized / replaced, you can implement your own `IViewModelFactory` and return an existing instance for some cases.

All the currently alive view models are retrievable via the `IViewModelManager`.

For more information, see the [docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Controlling+the+instantiation+of+view+models).